# Understanding why the following is not Reflexive.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

For the following question,

Determine whether the relation R on the set of all Webpages is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive, where (a, b) ∈ R if and only if

d)there is a Web page that includes links to both Webpage a and Web page b.

My initial thought was that R would be Reflexive since any page a belonging to R would also link to a, but apparently it is not Reflexive because there may be a page in R that has no links. I'm not sure how that makes sense since for a page to belong to R it must link to a page a and b, so how can there be a page on R that has no links?

Comment: That depends entirely on what set of webpages you are looking at.  If you are looking through all webpages, then consider that is is possible for a webpage to have almost no content on it whatsoever and there is nothing forcing a webpage to have a link to itself.  Take for example [this page](http://htwins.net/minesweeper/) where the only content on it is a minesweeper app and there are no links on it anywhere, in particular no links to itself.

Comment: Do not confuse $R$ with the set of all webpages.  $R$ is the *relation*.  The set of all webpages is something completely different.  "For a page to belong to $R$" is an incorrect thought since there are no webpages belonging to $R$, there are only *pairs* of webpages, the webpages coming from the universal set of webpages that we are considering, and specifically those pairs of webpages who link to oneanother.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now, I had been approaching the problem incorrectly. Now it makes sense that there may be a page x with links to a and b giving the relation aRb, but if page a has no links on it at all then there would be no relation aRa and it would make it not reflexive.

Comment: Whether a page $a$ has any links does not matter in whether in how it $R$-relates to other pages (or it self). By the definition of $R$ what matters is whether *other* pages link to it.

Answer (score 0):

a) It is not neccesarly reflexive since there is no need that every $a$ is linked to some Webpage.

b) It is definitively symmetric.

c) It is not neccesarly transitive. $a, b$ could be connected to some Web X and $b,c $ ar connected to some Web Y. But this says nothing about if $a,c$ are connected to some Web Z.